# calculate IRR on dateframe

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, irr

How calculate IRR on dateframe(df).
I have dateframe:

| ID | Amount_paid | Rate1 | Rate2 | Rate3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -3000 | 78,40 | 78,40 | 2500 |
| 2 | -200 | 28,60 | 28,60 | 28,60 |
| 3 | -4000 | 635,90 | 635,90 | 3600 |
| 4 | -1000 | 635,90 | 635,90 | 3600 |
| 5 | -800 | 635,90 | 635,90 | 3600 |

```
df['IRR']=npf.irr(df.iloc[:,1:])
```

> ValueError: Input must be a rank-1 array.

Comment: To calculate irr there must be at least one positive and at least one negative cash flow.  All the `amount_paid` values you show are negative.  Is there data not shown? Or are the cashflows those across the columns?  So calculate 5 irrs?

Comment: In Excel ID=1 
pay month -3000
 
loan installment 1 78,4
loan installment 2 78,4
loan installment 3 2500
 
 -4,08% ---> (Formula in Excel : IRR(all values ​​checked:-3000;78,4;78,4;78,4;2500)

Comment: for example works properly from ID=1: npf.irr(df.iloc[1,1:]) but from dateframe ValueError: Input must be a rank-1 array.

Answer (score 0):

`df.iloc[:,1:]` selects all three columns: `Rate1`, `Rate2` and `Rate3`. But `numpy.irr` requires a single array as an input. It fails when you pass it three columns.

Can you let me know what your desired output is?

Answer (score 0):

This works but there may be better ways to iterate through the dataframe.  I don't use pandas often.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy_financial as npf

df = pd.DataFrame()

df[ 'Amount_paid' ] = [ -3000, -200, -4000, -1000, -800 ]
df[ 'Rate1'] = [ 78.4, 28.6, 635.9, 635.9, 635.9 ]
df[ 'Rate2'] = [ 78.4, 28.6, 635.9, 635.9, 635.9 ]
df[ 'Rate3'] = [ 2500, 28.6, 3600, 3600, 3600 ]

result = []
for ix in range( len(df)):
    arr = df.iloc[ ix ]
    result.append( npf.irr(arr) )

result
# [-0.028570231670919766,
#  -0.3277960041116903,
#   0.07913479979420979,
#   0.930852297472391,
#   1.1442753876634035]

df[ 'IRR'] = result

df
#    Amount_paid  Rate1  Rate2   Rate3       IRR
# 0        -3000   78.4   78.4  2500.0 -0.040830
# 1         -200   28.6   28.6    28.6 -0.327796
# 2        -4000  635.9  635.9  3600.0  0.079135
# 3        -1000  635.9  635.9  3600.0  0.930852
# 4         -800  635.9  635.9  3600.0  1.144275
```

A version using df.apply

```
df[ 'IRR' ] = 0  # Reset 'IRR' to ensure apply does change it.
df[ 'IRR' ] = df.apply( npf.irr, axis = 1 )

df
#    Amount_paid  Rate1  Rate2   Rate3       IRR
# 0        -3000   78.4   78.4  2500.0 -0.040830
# 1         -200   28.6   28.6    28.6 -0.327796
# 2        -4000  635.9  635.9  3600.0  0.079135
# 3        -1000  635.9  635.9  3600.0  0.930852
# 4         -800  635.9  635.9  3600.0  1.144275
```

Comment: Yes apply works here.  That's the first time I've used it.  I've corrected the `Rate3` at the same time.